# plotly stacked box plot and density plot

Tags: r, plot, plotly

These are a few [good examples](https://plot.ly/ggplot2/geom_density/) on how to plot density or box plots separately.

However, I am looking for an example on how to plot a boxplot and its corresponding density plot stacked one on top of the other and not overlaid. The density plot should be on top. The boxplot on the bottom laid out across the x axis.

I am not sure how to do this, any advice or tips is much appreciated. Preferably using this toy dataset, just to keep it simple.

```
df <- data.frame(x <- rchisq(1000, 5, 10))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you are looking for something like this:

```
library(plotly)
df  <- data.frame(y = rchisq(1000, 5, 10))
fit <- density(df$y)

p1 <- plot_ly(df, x = fit$x, y = fit$y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') 
p2 <- plot_ly(df, y = ~y, type = 'box')
subplot(p1, p2, nrows = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: thats it, I just chaged the the 2nd plot from y =~y to x = ~y and it worked. This is so simple and powerful I love it. Thanks Martin